# skype outlook 2010 integration using different email ids

Tags: microsoft-outlook, skype

I am on outlook 2010 and skpye 6.2.

I have many contacts in outlook and skpype. But they have diffrent email id used in outlook and skype.
how can I intrigate them ?
When I try to ping someone from outlook it try to search person using its current email id but there is no way to add alternate mail id.
I used skpye tool bar for outlook 2007 which have this feature.

How to do same with default outlook skype plugin ?

Comment: What is your email config? Exchange?